# Strange error in JMS Topic setup using Spring

Tags: java, spring, jms

I am getting a JMS listener failure error messages when starting JBoss.
I am using Spring to setup a topic with two subscribers.
Here is my setup:

```
<bean id="offerListner" 
    class="org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="com.me.OfferListener" />
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="orderListener"
    class="org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="com.me.OrderListener" />
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>


<jms:listener-container  connection-factory="connectionFactory" acknowledge="transacted"  cache="connection" client-id="1" destination-type="durableTopic" >
    <jms:listener destination="eventTopic" ref="offerListener" />
    <jms:listener destination="eventTopic" ref="orderListener" />
</jms:listener-container>
```

When restarting JBoss I get a pattern of error message suggesting JBoss is struggling to initialize the JMS listener for my topic> This is the message I get:

```
2014-10-20 07:20:33,747 INFO  [STDOUT] (A2-2) 07:20:33,747  WARN DefaultMessageListenerContainer:842 - Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'eventTopic' - trying to recover. Cause: Cannot create a subscriber on the durable subscription since it already has subscriber(s)

2014-10-20 07:20:33,747 INFO  [STDOUT] (A2-2) 07:20:33,747  INFO DefaultMessageListenerContainer:891 - Successfully refreshed JMS Connection

2014-10-20 07:20:38,754 INFO  [STDOUT] (A2-3) 07:20:38,754  WARN DefaultMessageListenerContainer:842 - Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'eventTopic' - trying to recover. Cause: Cannot create a subscriber on the durable subscription since it already has subscriber(s)
```

...
and the message goes forever every 5 seconds.

My OrderListener and OfferListener both extend the same super class:

```
public class OfferListener extends AbstractListener {...}
public class OrderListener extends AbstractListener {...}
```

This is a simple representation of the classes:

```
public abstract class AbstractListener<T> {
      abstract protected void handleMessage(T message);

      @RunAsAdmin
      public void onMessage(Message message) {
        // pre-process the message, 
        handleMessage( processedMessage ); 
      }
}
```

There seem to be a problem in the AbstractListener method names.
**The Workaround Solution**

I can the problem if I define a unique marker interface for each listener, this for soem how uniquly identify each each listener, like this:

```
public class OfferListener extends AbstractListener implements OfferListenerMarker {...}
public class OrderListener extends AbstractListener implements OrderListenerMarker {...}
```

Both `OfferListenerMarker` and `OrderListenerMarker` are empty interfaces. This technique solves my problem but it's ugly and I don't understand why.
The issue seems to be related to JMS topic listeners having to have a unique identity. I thought the class itself (OrderListener and OfferListener) is a unique identity even if both extend the same abstract class.

I am trying to find away to get rid of the marker interface, there mus be something in the topic setup that I could do to?

Thanks for reading this thread.

Comment: Why do you wrap them in a `MessageListenerAdapter`? That shouldn't be needed (and could be the reason why you run into trouble).

Comment: `MessageListenerAdapter` can be extended or used as a wrapper class. I need to use it as a wrapper because the default message method has an aspect on it which will not be called if it is part of the same object.

Comment: That shouldn't matter (which makes me believe there is something else wrong). You shouldn't need it you should be able to reference your own class instance without problems (judging from your configuration that already is a `MessageListener`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It matters for the Aspect I have on my listener function. I originally extended MessageListenerAdapter but that led to the "Aspect" being ignored (because it became on the same object that invokes it). I will update the post to expose some of the guts of my classes.

Comment: As stated you shouldn't need that class at al. Just implement your handler and either let the listener-container wrap it in a `MessageListenerAdapter` (yes it does that) or make it a `MessageListener` yourself but that way there is only a single method. I think it isn't working (the aspect and the error you get) because you are making things too complex.

Comment: There seem to be a problem in the AbstractListener method names (handleMessage and onMessage). By changing those names to:

`abstract protected void handleEvent(T event);
@RunAsAdmin
public void handleMessage(final String message) {...}` seem to solve the problem and no need for marker interface.
I will try your suggestion by eliminating the need to `MessageListenerAdapter`. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. My problem disappeared when I renamed my abstract method handleMessage(T msg) to handleEvent(T evt) and onMessage(Message msg) to handleMessage(String msg). My JMS messages are of type TextMessage (JSON format). By doing that I don't need to use marker interface.
I also tried @M.Deinum's suggestion by eliminating the need for MessageListenerAdapter wrappere class, and that also worked for me, thanks to M.Deinum.

Answer (score 0):

Try providing a unique subscription name

```
<jms:listener-container  connection-factory="connectionFactory" acknowledge="transacted"  cache="connection" client-id="1" destination-type="durableTopic" >
    <jms:listener destination="eventTopic" ref="offerListener" subscription="xyz" />
    <jms:listener destination="eventTopic" ref="orderListener" subscription="abc" />
</jms:listener-container>
```

Basically to track durable subscriptions the JMS provider needs to be able to distinguish between two subscription.